# How to run npm through ssh

Tags: node.js, bash

After installing npm according to https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu/ , 3 lines were added at the end of `~/.bashrc` to load nvm tools.

When connecting to that server with ssh, `npm --version` outputs `5.5.1` as expected.

But when running remotely :

```
ssh server /bin/bash -l -c "npm --version"
```

I get :

> --version: npm: command not found

What is the correct way to have npm available when running it remotely in one line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is as you may suspect, your `.bashrc` is not being sourced. You had the right idea by adding the `-l` flag but what you really need in this case is the `-i` flag to spawn an **interactive** shell, in-turn sourcing your `.bashrc` prior to command execution.

```
ssh -t "server" 'bash -i -c "npm --version"'
```

**man `ssh`**

> If `command` is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.
>
> `-t` Force pseudo-terminal allocation.

**man `bash`**

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, if these files exist.

Comment: when i try this i get:  
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell

Comment: @TimBoland – I have updated my answer and added the `-t` flag to `ssh`. This flag will force pseudo-terminal allocation and should resolve your problem.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I've been banging my head against this for a long time. Bash is truly a garbage ecosystem

Answer (score 0):

I have my nvm.sh file in /etc/profile.d with the following content:

```
export NVM_DIR = "/ usr / local / nvm"
[-s "$ NVM_DIR / nvm.sh"] && \. "$ NVM_DIR / nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[-s "$ NVM_DIR / bash_completion"] && \. "$ NVM_DIR / bash_completion" # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

So to connect by ssh from another server I can do it by increasing previously `. /etc/profile.d/nvm.sh`, that is:

```
ssh -t "server" ". /etc/profile.d/nvm.sh && npm -v"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/why-doesnt-bashrc-run-automatically

It has both a solution and an explanation for the root cause of your problem. Normally you shouldn't have to specify anything at the `ssh` level - shell initialization is to supposed to be automatic and `ssh` is supposed to open an interactive shell.